# Problems with parse Query in ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I'm having trouble with this query.

[image: MyClass]

What i want to accomplish here is according to the idChatSeleccionadoAppUsuario(KYLmvSGP1…) i can have all the messages and User(Usuario) inside the list.
This is what i have tried so far:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Conversaciones");
    queryChat=ParseObject.createWithoutData("Chat",idChatSeleccionadoAppUsuario);
    query.whereEqualTo("ChatId", queryChat);
    query.include("Usuario");
    query.include("ChatId");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject obj : objects) {
                mensaje = obj.getString("Mensaje");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el mensaje" + mensaje);

                enviaMensaje = (ParseUser) obj.get("Usuario");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el usuario del chat---->:" + enviaMensaje.getObjectId());

                chatId = obj.getParseObject("ChatId");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el id del chat---->:" + chatId);
                //idChatSeleccionado=chatId.getObjectId();
                listaDeMensajes.add(obj);


            }
            mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(getContext(), listaDeMensajes);
            mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
            queryFromChat();


        }
    });

}
```

And also have tried this one:

```
 ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery(“Conversaciones”);
    query.whereEqualTo(“ChatId”, idChatSeleccionadoAppUsuario);
    query.include(“Usuario”);
    query.include(“ChatId”);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(List objects, ParseException e) {
    for (ParseObject obj : objects) {
    mensaje = obj.getString(“Mensaje”);
    Log.i(“UFF”, “Este es el mensaje” + mensaje);
     enviaMensaje = (ParseUser) obj.get("Usuario");
                    Log.i("UFF", "Este es el usuario del chat---->:" + enviaMensaje.getObjectId());

                chatId = obj.getParseObject("ChatId");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el id del chat---->:" + chatId);
                //idChatSeleccionado=chatId.getObjectId();
                listaDeMensajes.add(obj);


            }
            mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(getContext(), listaDeMensajes);
            mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
            queryFromChat();


        }
    });

  }
```

At the moment both return listaDeMensajes=0

Comment: Can you please print out the vars "object", "e" and share here?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo from query 1 or 2 and can you please suggest me which part you want me to print?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo from query 1 or 2 and can you please suggest me which part you want me to print? if you refer to List<ParseObject> objects the method isn`t even entering done on debugg.

Comment: That's strange. Do you see any error in your logs? "done" callback should be always called either with something in the "objects" var or an error in the "e" var. Can you print out both vars before the for just in case?

Comment: Thank you for reply @DaviMacêdo the query is working with the first one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is the way to retrieve the query... it was always but this post could help a lot of people...

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Conversaciones");
    queryChat=ParseObject.createWithoutData("Chat",idChatSeleccionadoAppUsuario);
    query.whereEqualTo("ChatId", queryChat);
    query.include("Usuario");
    query.include("ChatId");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject obj : objects) {
                mensaje = obj.getString("Mensaje");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el mensaje" + mensaje);

                enviaMensaje = (ParseUser) obj.get("Usuario");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el usuario del chat---->:" + enviaMensaje.getObjectId());

                chatId = obj.getParseObject("ChatId");
                Log.i("UFF", "Este es el id del chat---->:" + chatId);
                //idChatSeleccionado=chatId.getObjectId();
                listaDeMensajes.add(obj);


            }
            mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(getContext(), listaDeMensajes);
            mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
            queryFromChat();


        }
    });

}
```