# Problems with the ParseLiveQuery

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I made a parse query and now I need to implement the live query. But my query has a `List<ParseObject>` and I can see that here in this `liveQuery` method it is different.

```
        public void onEvent(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, final ParseObject object) {
```

ParseQuery is what this method has -- please refer to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047155/problems-with-parse-query-in-parseobject?noredirect=1#comment98770052_56047155)) to see that.

**This is the code suggested in the documentation:**

```
if (parseLiveQueryClient != null) {
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = new ParseQuery("Message");
parseQuery.whereEqualTo("destination", "pokelist");
SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> subscriptionHandling = parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(parseQuery);

subscriptionHandling.handleEvent(SubscriptionHandling.Event.CREATE, new SubscriptionHandling.HandleEventCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, final ParseObject object) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                EditText pokeText = findViewById(R.id.pokeText);
                numPokes++;
                if(numPokes == 1) {
                    pokeText.setText("Poked " + numPokes + " time.");
                }
                else {
                    pokeText.setText("Poked " + numPokes + " times.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

i made this and did update my list of messages. Any suggestions? I'm new in parse and am pretty confused!

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Conversaciones");
        queryChat = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Chat", idChatSeleccionadoAppUsuario);
        query.whereEqualTo("ChatId", queryChat);
        query.include("Usuario");
        query.include("ChatId");
        SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> subscriptionHandling= App.parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(query);
        subscriptionHandling.handleEvent(SubscriptionHandling.Event.CREATE, new SubscriptionHandling.HandleEventCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, final ParseObject object) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listaDeMensajes.add(object);
                    }

                });

                mMessageAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(getContext(), listaDeMensajes);
                mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
                queryFromChat();

            }
        });
```

Comment: I didn't really understand what's your issue. What's not working? Do you have any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem this is how ...

First make the subscription like this.

```
private void  changeChatLive(){
    listaDeMensajes.clear();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Conversaciones");
    // Connect to Parse server
    SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> subscriptionHandling = parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(query);

    // Listen for CREATE events
    subscriptionHandling.handleEvent(SubscriptionHandling.Event.CREATE, new
            SubscriptionHandling.HandleEventCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, ParseObject object) {

                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mMessageRecycler.scrollToPosition(0);
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Then i called the method here and voila the liveChat running. NOTE:Call the method where you need your live query to update!.

```
                queryConversaciones();
                mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                **changeChatLive();**
```